# Error downloading in-App product in android

Tags: in-app-purchase

when i try to purchase an item(in-app purchase item) from android  market, i get the following error, "product cannot be downloaded due to an error (-100)".What would be the reason for this ? Can anyone help me ?

Comment: see this link, maybe it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964878/application-error-billing/10965396#10965396